# Add applications to launcher

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop

I recently installed Matlab in `/usr/matlab`. What do I do to make it appear in the application launcher on the top left of the taskbar?

Comment: For MATLAB, the solution is to install the matlab-support package: `sudo apt install matlab-support`. It will create an application in the launcher.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a launcher to the panel by right clicking on a free area on the panel and selecting "Add to panel" and then "Custom Application Launcher" (or if the application is already present in the applications menu, you can select "Application Launcher" and then select the application from the menu).

You can add an entry into the applications menu by right clicking on it and selecting "Edit menu".

Comment: i tried it but it does not fully open man, as in only the logo of the program shows up and the program does not open.. where as if i type the same thing on the terminal, the program gets started without any problems what so ever

Comment: @john Right click on that launcher, and on __Type__ drop-down, select __Application in Terminal__. That way you'll get to see whatever error messages you get from the Terminal.

Comment: @John: My guess is that matlab requires some environment variables to be set and the install script wrote those into some rc file, which gets loaded when you open a shell, but not when you start gnome.